# Как при использовании selenium и переходе на другую страницу оставить имеющуюся авторизацию?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, get, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Имеется скрипт на Python с использованием selenium.
Суть заключается в том, что он открывает страницы и выдирает из них фотографии, но некоторые фотографии требуют авторизации, поэтому первым делом происходит авторизация через заполнение форм логина и пароля, поток клик по кнопке авторизации и собственно попадаю в авторизованный вид ВК.
Но при следующем запросе вида
`driver.get(url)`
получается что открывается страница без авторизации. Предполагаю что надо использовать cookies, но не совсем понимаю как это делать.
То есть имеется строка `allcoockie = driver.get_cookies()`, но я не особо понимаю как её применить к новооткрывающейся странице.Итого вопрос - каким образом можно оставить авторизованную страницу?

Comment: Сам нашёл - надо было просто подождать пока загрузится страница через time.sleep()

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно подождать до того как страница будет прогружена. Если не помогло, попробуй после применения кук обновить страницу.

Использовать .Sleep() не осветую. Лучше дожидатся того как страница будет полностью догружена браузером. Так будут исключатся ошибки на пустом месте при плохом соединении с интернетом.

Comment: Понятие "страница полностью загружена" достаточно сложное (можно просто подождать пока желаемый элемент не загрузится, используя WebDriverWait, но это не имеет никакого отношения к авторизации: к примеру, cookies посылаются серверу в *запросе* в заголовке — загрузка последующего *ответа* сервера никаким боком на успешность посылки cookies не влияет.

Comment: А то что нету таких методов в самом селениуме -- совсем уж не значит что это не возможно в принципе. Не такое уж и сложное, как кажется. Я же как-то напиал метод который дожидается конца прогрузки страницы и, даже, написал метод который дожидается конца обработки аджакс-запросов, который работает практически на всех сайтах :) При чем я эти методы написал как-то еще когда вообще садился учить селениум и шарп в принципе... Без особого опыта :)

Comment: фраза "достаточно сложно" не является синонимом "невозможно в принципе".  *«For every complex problem there is an answer that is clear, simple, and wrong.»*

Answer (score 0):

В итоге самым простым способом для первой загрузки оказался метод sleep() который ждал пока страница прогрузится. Как отмечали выше, это не самый безопасный способ в случае плохого соединения, однако в контексте быстрого решения проблемы - подходит.